# Visual Web Developer 2013 routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, visual-studio-exp-2013

I have setup a test website on visual Studio express  2013. I chose Framework 4.0 and webform based website with default structure.

-Default.asp

-About.aspx

-Contact.aspx

Above pages are automatically routed to as

`/` or `/Default` to Default.aspx

`/About` to About.aspx

`/Contact` to Contact.aspx

In visual studio 2010 we had to create routing path in `Global.asax` file but in this case  my `Global.asax` file has no routing defined so how is this routing automatically.

Suppose if i need to create a routing path `Sports/football` how can i create that or should i create a routing path in global.asax file and map it to the `aspx` file

Can same project work on web server which has IIS 7.5 and .Net Framework 4.0 installed?

Comment: It seems it is because of `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`

Comment: It is because of Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls...  But you can still specify more routes of your own if you want.  just call RouteTable.Routes.Add(...) in global.asax -> Application_Starting.

Comment: @Ryios, Thanks, Which one of them is more flexible or better.

Comment: FriendlyUrls is automatic with webforms "e.g. aspx files"... If you want to manually specify routes you have to add routes to the route table or use the UrlRewriter module.